# FormBuilder and Mosaico installation problems

Tags: mosaico, message-templates, formbuilder

I've got a CiviCRM v 5.57.0 site running on WordPress v6.1.1 and I have the following symptoms on an otherwise healthy site:

- FormBuilder isn't working, I can only see tokens on the UI
- I can't view Mosaico Templates - once I've created one, I can select it when creating a new mailing so I know it is saved, but when I go to the page to view the Templates (which uses FormBuilder), there are none displayed
- When trying to create a 'traditional' mailing, I can't upload an image and the error message says "Cannot write to upload folder." but the permissions for civicrm/persist/contribute/images/uploads folder is 775
- Possibly related, I have also attempted to install Mosaico Message Templates but it doesn't install and I don't get any error messages

This is what I see when I try to view the FormBuilder UI:
[image: broken FormBuilder UI]

I'm also getting lots of error messages in the browser console like
`Uncaught Error: Can only have one anonymous define call per script file`
and
`Uncaught TypeError: n is undefined`

I'm really not sure where to look so any help would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issues with my Joomla site. If you already have Civigrant installed it must be enabled or completely uninstalled. Weird, I know, but it is true. Something conflicts. If Civigrant is already installed but disabled and not needed it is best to uninstall it completely or it can still cause issues. My guess it has something to do with the code, since it once was part of core and is now an extension. Then you will want to disable Mosaico, Search Kit, and Form Core (I believe that is the full list.) Then, you will want to enable them 1 at a time. Search kit, form core, then Mosaico. Clear cache and test. See if that helps you too. If just disabling and enabling in that order doesn't work, try uninstalling the extensions and reinstalling in that order.